# What is a word for the most basic form of a term?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The English language contains very descriptive and "involved" words, I was wondering what we would call the opposite of those.

For example, words like "push" or "hot" can't be simplified further without losing their meaning. What do you call a term in its most basic form?

Example:

> *scorching* may imply a very high level of *heat* or *hot*.
>   *heat* or *hot* are basic terms that don't imply any enhancement (How hot, how much heat).

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What are examples of descriptive and involved words? And what do you mean that a word can or cannot be simplified?

Comment: I am not sure what is being asked. Are we looking for the simplest idea or the shortest word?

Comment: Just for amusement, in Platos Theory of Ideas (or Forms) the idea (or form) is just that: The basic essence of anything.

Comment: Would *canonical* be appropriate?

Comment: Eleven very different answers posted in rapid succession are the best indicator that the question is insufficiently clear. It would be a start if you indicated the part of speech you are after, and the domain we're talking about (linguistics? philosophy? psychology?). And it would help if you could define what actually constitutes a simplification without losing meaning, and provide examples. After all, any dictionary entry is just that, and both *hot* and *push* do have an entry in most every dictionary.

Comment: After the clarification, I think what you are asking is a "base word" and it differs from "root word". Base words stand on its own, apparent in every language and are words in its simplest form. I can give this as an answer if it is re-opened.

Comment: Full disclosure: I made the distinction example based upon my understanding of the question. It may have exceeded the bounds of a common edit, but in my opinion, it complies with the intent of the original question. The question asked about *idea* but I think *term* is a better word, consider the OP example of *hot* or *push* (not so much ideas, but terms).

Comment: @SrJoven: You might not have enough reputation to vote for reopening but you can request in Meta site with an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

[*essence*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/essence): the intrinsic or indispensable properties that serve to characterize or identify something; the crucial element. **in essence**: by nature

From Latin *esse*, *to be*.

Synonyms include *substance, gist, core, sum, marrow, heart, center, hypostasis (essential nature or underlying reality), haecceity, quiddity (the essence that makes something the kind of thing it is and makes it different from any other)
**quintessence** (the purest and most concentrated essence of something), stuff

Answer (score 4):

*Irreducible* concepts are *axiomatic*.

> An axiomatic concept is the identification of a primary fact of
>   reality, which cannot be analyzed, i.e., reduced to other facts or
>   broken into component parts.

Answer (score 3):

germ

It's sort of customary to call such a thing the germ of an idea.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/germ

(scroll down to see **22** "the germ of a brilliant idea")

Comment: @carsmack Read the simple, short Q. Your usage is right, of course, which makes this the needed answer.

Comment: @carsmack It may be a good idea for you to delete your comment as it seems to have already earned the answer a down vote and can continue to do so. Thanks.

Comment: _Germ_ implies growth though, which is not necessarily part of the stated question.

Comment: @200 Forget **that** *germ,* this is the 22nd sense (ODO) with several other distinct meanings & usages in between. (e. g., a germ is also a microorganism of any age, unrelated to growth.) HTH.

Comment: "Germ of a brilliant idea" has a context of growth, as @200_success mentioned. While one can literally argue that "initial stage from which something can develop" could also apply to "a word describing a very simple idea", it does not flow idiomatically for me.

Comment: @Lynn et al, what's the problem with growth? That something can grow doesn't mean it's not the smallest thing there is. The most basic form of an animal might be a zygote. That it can grow doesn't mean it's not the smallest.

Comment: @SrJoven - It doesn't mean it *is* the smallest either.  And there can be things which "can't be simplified further" which also cannot grow further.  There is some overlap with germ, but I really don't think it's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Lynn I agree that the OP isn't looking for germ in the sense of the question, but I don't understand the issue with grow as a problem with something being small.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a special word in reference to words.  However, I think *atomic* is what I would use to describe the concept of a word that could not be broken down any further:

> of or forming a single irreducible unit or component in a larger system. [Google definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=atomic+grill&oq=atomic)

Answer (score 1):

**Elementary,** my dear dude.  It fits your request, in [multiple senses](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elementary) of the word:

> 1. Relating to the rudiments of a subject
>
>    1.1 Of the most basic kind
>      1.2 Straightforward and uncomplicated
> 2. Not decomposable into elements or other primary constituents.

You asked for a word to describe words that "can't be simplified without losing meaning".  "Elementary" means both "simple" (as in elementary school) and "cannot be broken down" (as in elementary particles).

Answer (score 0):

I would call it the *core idea, essential idea* or *basic idea.*

Answer (score 0):

it's possible you're looking for the "platonic form" of XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

The word that I would use is 'gist'

Merriam Webster - The main point or part:  Essence

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gist

Edit: Never mind, I answered the title, not the question.